# Order By within the Partition

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Need a Select Query for the following scenario, using Microsoft SQL Server 2008

```
Order Customer Order_Type
1     A        NULL
2     A        NULL
3     B        S
4     C        NULL
5     D        S
6     B        NULL
7     D        S
```

I want to order by Customer who have placed Order Type S, So the output I am expecting is as follows

```
Order Customer Order_Type
3     B        S
6     B        NULL
5     D        S
7     D        S
1     A        NULL
2     A        NULL
4     C        NULL
```

Customer who placed Order Type 'S' should bubble to the top but the order of the those customer still has to be by Customer as for the rest of them. Here is the query I am using

```
SELECT *
    FROM CustomerOrder      
    ORDER BY COUNT(CASE WHEN Order_Type = 'S' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer) DESC, 
             Customer
```

But the output I am getting is

```
Order Customer Order_Type
5     D        S
7     D        S
3     B        S
6     B        NULL
1     A        NULL
2     A        NULL
4     C        NULL
```

It is because of the order by on the count.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3162c/5

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `MAX()` instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM CustomerOrder      
ORDER BY MAX(CASE WHEN Order_Type = 'S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer) DESC, 
         Customer;
```

Comment: Thanks, that was quick. Will accept it as an answer.